I am using the Dyanmixel SDK with python to move an XM540-W270. I can detect but not move it. Has anyone run into this issue or found a solution?
I connected the XM540-W270 dynamixel computer to my computer. I also downloed the dynamixel sdk and get it installed on my mac machine. I ran the python script ping.py and was able to ping the motor as seen below.
But when I ran the read_write.py I can connect to the motor but I am unable to move it. As seen below.

My address table also all matches up with the XM540-W270.

Has anyone run into this issue? Or have any ideas on how to get the servo to move?

The problem was that the servo was in velocity mode not position mode.
